# MongoDB / Mongoose - Return only array items that matches $text

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, full-text-search

I have the following object:

```
user: {
 _id: "xxx",
 name: "Lucas",
 items: [
  { name: "shoes", description: "nice shoes" },
  { name: "pants", description: "old pants" },
 ],
 places: [
  {name: "my house", loc: { type: "Point", coordinates: [-27, -43] }}
 ]
}
```

I need to perform a text-search ($text) that returns only the items.
For example:

```
await User.find({ $text: { $search: "shoes" } });
```

This works! But it also returns pants, since it returns the user and not only the array item. And that is the problem, i need to paginate over the items in my database. So I need to return only the array items that matches the $text search. I know that if items was a collection itself it would work, but in my case I need those inside the user because I combine $text for items and $geoWithin for places.

So, how do I return the User keeping only his items that matched my $text search?

Comment: Nice problem. But I wonder if there is nice way to solve this without putting items in a separate collection. You can use lookup aggregation to join users and items, so it is not a problem to combine them.

Comment: You mean like, creating a View joining Users and Clothes as 2 different collections, and query this view?

Comment: I mean [lookup aggregation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup) Or even mongoose populate

Comment: Ok, I will give it a try. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use regex 
To include a regular expression in a comma-separated list of query conditions for the field, use the $regex operator. For example:

```
{ name: { $regex: /acme.*corp/i, $nin: [ 'acmeblahcorp' ] } }
```

or smth like

```
db.users.find({"name": /^m/})
```

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/

Comment: I am not very familiar with regex. Does it work as a text search or it only finds in case of string being exactly the same? For example: if i have an item named "Mario T-Shirt", and the user searches for "Mario", would regex be able to find?